# WPF Performance Tool To Show When UI Thread Locks and For How Long

Tags: c#, wpf, performance-testing, ui-thread

I'm sure this already exists, but haven't been able to find it.  I'm looking for a WPF control that displays some sort of animation on my app so I can easily tell when the UI thread locks.  I'm looking for the control to also show me how long the UI thread was locked for.  This would be a development tool that I would only enable when running in Debug mode, and would be used to identify performance problems in my app when the UI is unresponsive for long periods of time.  So I'm looking for something similar to the [Visual Studio PerfWatson Monitor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a3c888f2-40e0-4370-83e0-2952febf9e4f).

I know I could write one myself, but I'm sure others have already done this (and probably better than I could). If you know of one could you please share it with me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was going to reply to this yesterday but didn't have a full solution, just a suggestion!

I have done something like this and created a control which subscribes to CompositionTarget.Rendering as a simple indicator of 'UI Thread busyness', then plots the framerate (1.0/time between events) on a very small strip chart updating once per second. The strip chart in question is very lightweight and uses bitmaps not WPF elements so it doesn't use much CPU time. The control can be overlaid on any WPF form as an adorner to debug perf issues.

[image]

This is very revealing as it shows in real-time the UI thread drop-outs.

Sorry I can't share any code as its proprietary to my company, but thought it would give you an idea of how to solve this problem.

Comment: screenshots, code, both covered by NDA ;-) Imagine Windows task manager chart but showing 1.0/CompositionTarget.Rendering time between events

Comment: Are you able to run up the relevant code in a test app? I imagined what you describe but the OP may not share our mind's-eye.

Comment: Great! It might be worth launching this control in a separate window, with a separate dispatcher so that a locked UI won't lock the frame rate chart.

Comment: Well it doesn't matter if it does, because we are timing the CompositionTarget.Rendering event (time between events). so if the chart is locked on update (remember I suggested only refreshing it every 1 second) then it will still show dropouts. Just plot X=SampleNumber by Y=1.0/TimeBetweenEvents. To get it to work smoothly I use a 10-period moving average to smooth out the time so it doesn't jump around so fast. I found interestingly CompTarget.Rendering averages 60FPS when idle, 120FPS when mouse moving (?) and drops to 5-10 when UI thread is really busy.

Answer (score 0):

Create a control template for *any control* that contains only a spinning rectangle.

Then, add the control at from code behind when you are in debug mode to ensure that it doesnt creep into release.

```
#if DEBUG
if(runtimeCondition)
{
    //add or unhide control
}
#end if
```

Really easy to implement, here is a template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="spinningSquareTemplate">
            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="OnLoaded1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </ControlTemplate.Resources>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="#FFFFB900" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                        <TranslateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnLoaded1}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
```

When your UI locks, the square will stop spinning.